# How to get user info using Office-js-helper's Authentication?

Tags: javascript, authentication, office-js, office-addins, exceljs

I am working on `Excel Web Add-In`. I am using [OfficeDev/office-js-helpers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers) library for authenticating user. Following code is working fine. But I don't know how to get user's email, user name etc.

Is there any function available in `OfficeDev/office-js-helpers`  through which I can get user info ?

```
if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) {
  return;
}

var authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();

// register Microsoft (Azure AD 2.0 Converged auth) endpoint using
authenticator.endpoints.registerMicrosoftAuth('clientID');

// for the default Microsoft endpoint
authenticator
    .authenticate(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.Microsoft)
    .then(function (token) { 
    /* My code after authentication and here I need user's info */ })
    .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
```

Code sample will be much helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This code only provides you the `token` for the user. In order to obtain information about the user, you'll need to make calls into [Microsoft Graph API](http://graph.microsoft.io/). You can find a full set of documentation on that site.

If you're only authenticating in order to get profile information, I'd recommend looking at [Enable single sign-on for Office Add-ins (preview)](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins). This is a much cleaner method of obtaining an access token for a user. It is still in preview at the moment so it's feasibility will depend on where you're planning to deploy your add-in.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is not there any clean code sample available  for getting user's basic info in `OfficeDev/office-js-helpers `? Links you provided has theory concept more but very less code sample

Comment: @user3881465 you can get code samples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the Microsoft token, you can send a request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ to get user information. This request *must* have an authorization header containing the token you got previously.

Here is an example using axios :

```
const config = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}` };
axios.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`, {
    headers: config
}).then((data)=> {
    console.log(data); // data contains user information
};
```